# Mouseover on 'favorite tags' section on index does not show popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-bubble, tag-watching

Mouseovering most tags results in the display of a floating window with subscription options, among other things. However, the tags displayed in the favorite tags box in the upper right of the index page does not respond to mouseover.

Note - I consider this a bug because every other case of tags I can find has the same behavior - it seems like it was just an oversight that the favorites tag window, which is very prominent, fails to have the mouseover while eg, recent tags, located below the fold, does have the mouseover. They're also visually virtually the same as every other tag, so it's not immediately obvious why the popup does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this wasn't an oversight; the tag hover menu was explicitly disabled in the "favorite tags" section. The reasoning was that when you unfavorite a tag (through the hover menu), the corresponding tag is removed from the "favorite" section.

So if the menu was created by hovering a tag in the "favorite" section, and you unfavorite from there, the tag gets removed, but the menu (that was created from this tag) is still there. This feels somewhat weird.

However, we've received some feedback (including this very post of yours) that the incosistency in the tag behavior might be even more confusing, so we'll remove the restriction in the next build.